# Using inverse function with transforming geometry into coordinates results into mixed SRID error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using postgres with postig extension. I have coordinates which I put into following postgis function:

```
select ST_SetSRID(ST_point(18.533935546875, 48.23199134320962),4674)
```

As a result, I get geometry type: 01010000204212000000000000B08832402D0570E4B11D4840

When I want to do inverse action

```
select st_x(st_transform(way,4326)), st_y(st_transform(way,4326)) from planet_osm_point where way ='01010000204212000000000000B08832402D0570E4B11D4840'
```

I get error:

```
ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
********** Error **********
ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
SQL state: XX000
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somewhat described in the error message: you are trying to find equal geometries in `planet_osm_point.way`, but they have a different SRID than 4674. It is effectively this:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0, 0), 4674) = ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0, 0), 4326);
```

So you would need to pick a common SRID, and transform one to the other, i.e.

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0, 0), 4674) =
                      ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0, 0), 4326), 4674);
```

except I don't recommend using the `=(geometry, geometry)` operator since it requires identical geometries, which are not very common with floating point errors after transforming.

A better approach is to find all the `way` geometries within a small margin of error distance using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

```
select st_x(st_transform(way,4326)), st_y(st_transform(way,4326))
from planet_osm_point
where ST_DWithin(
         way,
         ST_Transform(
           ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(18.533935546875, 48.23199134320962), 4674),
           <way_SRID>),
         1e-6);
```

Here, it transforms the point into the SRID of `way` (you never specified, so update `<way_SRID>`), then find anything within 1e-6 degrees distance away (about 10 cm). Increase it if you want to collect more nearby `way` points.